# Reset auto-incrementing column (alternative method)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, auto-increment, reset

Good evening, guys. Here's my case:

First of all, I'm working with MySQL through phpMyAdmin (which I'm just starting to learn by the way). I've got 4 columns in my table, 2 of which are auto-incrementing columns: `meta_id` and `post_id`. Both are `BIGINT` so they both grow on number every time an image is added through Media Library in Wordpress. I truncated all the data, used `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`, and started adding new media. But after that I realized that the reset only had effect on the `PRIMARY` column, like so:

```
+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key  | meta_value |
+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 1       | 97402   | something | something  |
| 2       | 97403   | sth       | sth        |
| 3       | 97404   | sth       | sth        |
...
```

So how can I reset both and not only the `PRIMARY`?

Thanks in advance, guys :)

Comment: can you do a `show create table tablenameXYZ` please?

Comment: What do you need that for, @Drew?

Comment: cuz I would love to know how a table is created with 2 auto_incs

Comment: phpmyadmin open table goto menu operation and choose `empty the data table`

Comment: That's what I needed, @mohsen :) But what happens if I need to keep part of the data inside that table? Should I just export it, empty the table and import the data back in?

Comment: yes you can do that with export with data or without in menu bar ! and import it again and also you can edit the sql file manually!

Comment: @Drew, it seems there was something I didn't realize. The second column is not an auto-increment kind of column. The `post_id` value is provided by Wordpress when uploading new media. So thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: it either has to be a trigger, some code that does a max()+1, or something. But not a 2nd auto_inc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on phpmyadmin:
 open table goto menubar `operation` and choose `empty the data table(truncate)`

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible with plain SQL:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `table_name`;
```

This means it can be also done programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for adding that useful tip, @jpaljasma :)